# JavaScript refresh the page after few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I'm trying to refresh the page every 18 minutes with JavaScript, but my code doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
function startChecking() {
    secondsleft -= 1e3;
    if (secondsleft <= 3e4) {
        document.getElementById("div_countdown").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML = Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds"
    }
}

function startschedule() {
    clearInterval(timeout);
    clearInterval(interval);
    timeout = setTimeout("window.location.href=window.location.href;", threshold);
    secondsleft = threshold;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        startChecking()
    }, 1e3)
}

function resetTimer() {
    startschedule();
    document.getElementById("div_countdown").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML = ""
}
var timeout, interval;
var threshold = 108e4;
var secondsleft = threshold;
startschedule();
window.onload = function() {
    startschedule()
}

<a id="div_countdown" style="display:none;" onclick="javascript:resetTimer();">Chat Will Refresh in <span id="timercounter"></span> Click <font color="#FA5882">here</font> to Cancel</a>
```

When I go to the page it will wait 18 minutes then if 30 seconds left to refresh, it will display 30 seconds and count it to 0 when it hits 0 it will refresh the page and start again.

But when 30 seconds left and if I clicked that 30 seconds it won't refresh but it will reset timer to 18 minutes.

I want to make another button, when I click on it, button must hide and timer must stop for the session, until I re-open browser. How would I be able to fix it?

Comment: For clearing the timeout use `clearTimeout` and not `clearInterval`: `clearInterval(timeout);` -> `clearTimeout(timeout);`

Comment: didn't get it..

Comment: in your code you create an interval and a timeout. When clearing the interval use the `clearInterval` method. When clearing the timeout you should use `clearTimeout` and not `clearInterval`. Inside your `startschedule` function at the first line

Answer (score 0):

The only changes are shorter delays (Can't wait 18 minutes to debug a script).

in `startChecking()`, since you show the seconds left, you should decrease the value by 1000 (1 second) and also divide `secondsleft` by 1000...

The interval also should be 1000.

That leaves two customizable numbers...
`threshold` for your 18 minutes max time...
and the amount when to show the message in the condition `if (secondsleft <= 10000)`

As [quirimmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2652759/quirimmo) mentionned in comments, the `clearInterval()` on the timeout should be `clearTimeout()`.

```js
function startChecking() {
    secondsleft -= 1000;
    if (secondsleft <= 10000) {
        document.getElementById("div_countdown").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML = Math.abs(secondsleft / 1000) + " Seconds"
    }
}

function startschedule() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    clearInterval(interval);
    timeout = setTimeout("window.location.href=window.location.href;", threshold);
    secondsleft = threshold;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        startChecking()
    }, 1000)
}

function resetTimer() {
    startschedule();
    document.getElementById("div_countdown").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML = ""
}
var timeout, interval;
var threshold = 12000;
var secondsleft = threshold;
startschedule();
window.onload = function() {
    startschedule()
}
```

```html
<a id="div_countdown" style="display:none;" onclick="javascript:resetTimer();">Chat Will Refresh in 
  <span id="timercounter"></span> Click <font color="#FA5882">here</font> to Cancel
</a>
```

The page doesn't refresh in the snippet above, but it does in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XaEgQo?editors=1010)